# Constructor cannot be applied to given types; required: Parcel; actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: android, builder, lombok, parcel

I'm working on an app in Android Studio and want to transfer data from my City instance to next activity by intent. To do that, I generated the Parcelable code with Plugin "Android Parcelable code generator".

Now I'm getting the following error message during compile time:

```
Error:(19, 1) error: constructor City in class City cannot be applied to given types;
    required: Parcel
    found: boolean,String,int[],LatLng
    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

City class:

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Builder(builderMethodName = "hiddenBuilder")
@ToString
public class City implements Parcelable {

    private boolean isSolved;
    private final String name;
    private int[] imageIds;
    private LatLng latLng;

    public static CityBuilder builder(String name) {
        return hiddenBuilder().name(name);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeByte(this.isSolved ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0);
        dest.writeString(this.name);
        dest.writeIntArray(this.imageIds);
        dest.writeParcelable(this.latLng, flags);
    }

    protected City(Parcel in) {
        this.isSolved = in.readByte() != 0;
        this.name = in.readString();
        this.imageIds = in.createIntArray();
        this.latLng = in.readParcelable(LatLng.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<City> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<City>() {
        @Override
        public City createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new City(source);
        }

        @Override
        public City[] newArray(int size) {
            return new City[size];
        }
    };
}
```

What needs to be done to make Lombok's Builder Annotation work with Parcel?

Comment: can you try adding parameterized constructor with boolean,String,int[],LatLng in POJO?

Comment: add you builder class please

Comment: @Oussema Aroua: Builder class is generated by lombok.

Comment: @Reena: Your hint was correct. Thanks alot!

Comment: Yep, Welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add parameterized constructor with boolean,String,int[],LatLng in your POJO, You can refer following code:

```
 public City(boolean isSolved, String name,int[] imageIds,LatLng  latLng) {
        this.isSolved = isSolved;
        this.name = name;
        this.imageIds = imageIds;
        this.latLng = latLng;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The hint from Reena with all arg constructor in POJO made it work. Does anyone have an explanation why this is necessary?

Btw: LatLng is not Serializable. I had to exchange it with an own wrapper.

Full example with all arg constructor:

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import com.my.project.Coordinate;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Builder(builderMethodName = "hiddenBuilder")
@ToString
public class City implements Parcelable {

    private boolean isSolved;
    private final String name;
    private int[] imageIds;
    private Coordinate coordinate;

    public City(final boolean isSolved, final String name,
                final int[] imageIds, final Coordinate coordinate) {
        this.isSolved = isSolved;
        this.name = name;
        this.imageIds = imageIds;
        this.coordinate = coordinate;
    }

    public static CityBuilder builder(String name) {
        return hiddenBuilder().name(name);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeByte(this.isSolved ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0);
        dest.writeString(this.name);
        dest.writeIntArray(this.imageIds);
        dest.writeParcelable(this.coordinate, flags);
    }

    protected City(Parcel in) {
        this.isSolved = in.readByte() != 0;
        this.name = in.readString();
        this.imageIds = in.createIntArray();
        this.coordinate = in.readParcelable(Coordinate.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<City> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<City>() {
        @Override
        public City createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new City(source);
        }

        @Override
        public City[] newArray(int size) {
            return new City[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You May Need Constructor Sir in City Class

```
public class City implements Parcelable {

    private boolean isSolved;
    private final String name;
    private int[] imageIds;
    private LatLng latLng;

    .....................
    public City(){
    // You can leave it blank
    }
    .....................
}
```